# Procmon - Why do I see multiple CreateFile & CloseFile calls by a partiuclar process on its own executable

Tags: procmon

Please see below image.
I just want to know, why chrome.exe is calling CreateFile & CloseFile functions on its own executable multiple time. What is the reason behind this?

[image: Chrome process in Procmon]

[image]

Thanks!